# BibLaTeX `@set` in authoryear style for translated article

Tags: biblatex

When using the `@set` entry type in combination with the authoryear style in BibLaTeX, I obtain unexpected results. Instead of giving the correct year for each entry in the set, the year of the main entry gets repeated.

An example explains this better:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@SET{set,
  entryset = {original,translation}
}

@ARTICLE{original,
  author = {Author, A.},
  journal = {Journal de France},
  year = {1999}
}

@ARTICLE{translation,
  author = {Author, A.},
  journal = {American Journal},
  year = {2000},
  translator = {Traducteur, T.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{set}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]

I would have expected the second appearance of 1999 to give 2000... Or maybe, that the bibliography style would change on subsequent set entries. Could someone clarify this to me or propose a workaround?

Comment: The second year should indeed be 2000. We're already looking at edits to date label handling, so this will get fixed soon. In the meantime you should consider using the (also biber-only) related entries feature. The entry `vangennep:related` from `biblatex-examples.bib` shows how you can relate an original work to its translation.

Comment: @Audrey understood my question better than myself. Her comment led to an acceptable answer. I will reformulate my question and give the answer myself.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use the the `related` and `relatedtype` fields instead of the `@set` entry type. There is a `relatedtype` called `bytranslator` defined by default. However, it is meant to be used in combination with `@book` entries rather than `@article` entries as in your case. But you can still define your own `relatedtype` as shown in the example below:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{original,
  author = {Auteur, A.},
  journal = {Journal de France},
  year = {1999},
  title = {Always English},
  related = {translation},
  relatedtype = {articletranslatedin}
}

@ARTICLE{translation,
  author = {Author, A.},
  journal = {American Journal},
  year = {2000},
  title = {Always English},
  translator = {Traducteur, T.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
%% Here we basically just re-use code from different places in BibLaTeX
\newbibmacro*{related:articletranslatedin}[1]{%
 \entrydata{#1}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{name:hook}[1]{%
   \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\begingroup
     \mkrelatedstring%
     \lbx@initnamehook{#1}%
     \endgroup}
    {}}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\printdate}
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
   {\printfield{issn}}
   {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{original}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Result after compilation]

But be careful with this example. It is not very portable and expects the following:

1. The `author` should be the same in both entries. It is therefore omitted in the related article. We do not check for differing names.
2. The `title` is expected to be the same as well and is omitted for the second entry.